# Como apagar dado usando angular, php e ui-route?

Tags: php, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer um método para apagar um registro do banco e a seguinte mensagem parece no console:

> GET http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/VigilantesComunitarios/admin/php/apagaPais.php?idPais=undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)

Estou usando ui-router do angular.

Seguem meus códigos:

html:

```
<table width="200">
    <tr>
        <td><b>País</b></td>
        <td><b>Sala</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="pais in paises">
        <td>{{pais.nome}}</td>
        <td>{{pais.sala}}</td>
        <td><a ui-sref="editarPais({idPais: pais.idPais})">[ ]</a></td>
        <td><a ng-click="apagarPais(pais.idPais)">[x]</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Angular:

```
app.controller("PaisesController", function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state) {

$scope.apagarPais = function (pais) {
    console.log("id "+pais);
    $http.get("admin/php/apagaPais.php?idPais="+pais)
    .success(function (data, status){
        console.log(data);
        carregaPaises();
    });
};

carregaPaises();

});
```

php:

```
include_once("conexao.php");
$pdo = conectar();

$id = $_POST['idPais'];
print_r($id);

$apagaPais=$pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM paises WHERE idPais=:id");
$apagaPais->bindValue(":id", $id);
$apagaPais->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa informar o PHP qual o ID deve ser removido, para isso você precisa ENVIAR o ID do angular para o PHP.

Use `$http.post` ao invés de `$http.get`.

Outra observação, o método `.then()` só vai funcionar se você tiver uma `promise` sendo retornada, que não é o caso do método `.get`. O erro pode ser por isso, mas ainda assim, a exclusão não vai funcionar.

Comment: Fiz as alterações e a mensagem continua.
"POST http://localhost:8888/sistemas/sistemas_web/VigilantesComunitarios/admin/php/apagaPais.php?idPais=undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Atualizei o post, aqui, com as correções que sugeriste.

Comment: Como já respondi em outras questões suas, utilize os métodos de print e console. Esse erro por si só já diz tudo, houve algum erro interno do servidor, não tendo ligação com o angular. O $id está realmente pegando o valor correto?

Comment: Já tinha colocado console e print_r.
O console, mostra o id que está sendo passado.
Já o print_r não retorna nada.
Coloquei no código, aqui do post, os consoles e prints que coloquei no meu código para ver o que retorna.
Só o primeiro console que mostra o id, o print não chega a aparecer.

Comment: Consegui passar o id como parâmetro, veja como fiz na atualização do código, aqui no post.
Porém, ainda mostra erro de servidor.

Comment: Consegui. Eu estava fazendo include com o arquivo de conexão errado.

Comment: Pois é, tava achando estranho o erro de server, normalmente se for erro no angular, ele vem com um link para o site do próprio angular, onde contém uma descrição do que pode estar acontecendo. Mas se conseguiu resolver, ótimo! =D